# Norm of wedge product of forms

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact Riemannian manifold. Assume that $\omega \in \Omega^p(M)$ and $\omega'\in \Omega^q(M)$ are $p$ and $q$-forms with constant and non-null norms, i.e,
$$\|\omega(p)\| = C > 0,~\|\omega'(p)\| = D > 0,~\forall p \in M.$$

One can assume that $\omega$ and $\omega'$ are closed. Is there a sufficient condition in order to $$\max_{p\in M}\|\omega\wedge\omega'\| \neq 0?$$

I was expecting that some formula like
$$\|\omega\wedge \omega'\|^2 = \|\omega\|^2\|\omega'\|^2 - \langle \omega,\omega'\rangle^2$$
would work (is this formula true?).

In this case, since $\omega$ and $\omega'$ are closed, $\langle \omega,\omega'\rangle$ would be constant. Therefore, if there is a point $p\in M$ such that $\cos^2\varphi\neq 1$ one will have the claim, where $\varphi$ is the angle between $\omega$ and $\omega'$.

What do you think?

Comment: What is the definition of $\langle \omega, \omega'\rangle$?